# Show that a vector field both irrotational and solenoidal is the gradient of a harmonic function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let G denote a vector field that is continuously differentiable on some open interval S in 3-space.

Consider:

i) curl G = 0 and G = curl F for some c. differentiable vector field F. That is,  curl( curl F) = 0 everywhere on S

ii) a scalar field $\varphi$ exists such that $\nabla\varphi$ is continuously differentiable and such that:

F = $\nabla\varphi$ and $\nabla^2\varphi = 0$ everywhere on S.

Prove that i) implies ii).

Attempt:

Since curl( curl F) = 0, we have that grad(div F) = $\nabla^2$F. For $F=(F_1,F_2,F_3,)$, it is equal:

$(\partial^2F_1/\partial x^2 + \partial^2F_1/\partial y^2 + \partial^2F_1/\partial z^2 , \partial^2F_2/\partial x^2+\partial^2F_2/\partial y^2 +\partial^2F_2/\partial z^2  , \partial^2F_3/\partial x^2 +\partial^2F_3/\partial y^2  + \partial^2F_3/\partial z^2 )$ =

$(\partial^2F_1/\partial x^2 +\partial^2F_2/\partial xy +\partial^2F_3/\partial xz,  \partial^2F_1/\partial yx +  \partial^2F_2/\partial y^2  +\partial^2F_3/\partial yz, \partial^2F_1/\partial zx +\partial^2F_2/\partial zy +\partial^2F_3/\partial z^2)  $

I cannot go further than here. Equalling all the vectors components doesn't seem to help.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I know:

If ${\bf curl}({\bf G}) = 0$, then ${\bf G}$ can be written as follows (Helmholz decomposition)
$${\bf G} = {\bf grad}\,\varphi+{\bf c}\tag1$$
 where ${\bf c}$ is a constant vector.

If ${\bf G} = {\bf curl}\,{\bf F}$ then taking the divergence of $(1)$

$$div\,{\bf G} = \triangle\,\varphi=0$$

Because $div({\,curl}\,{\bf F}) =0$

Hope this helps to find your solution